# How to infer type in static generic method with the type of the caller in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, static, protocols

I'm declaring this method on a protocol extention

```
protocol Storable { ... }

extention Storable {
    static func get<T: Decodable>(by identifier: String, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void)
    ...
}
```

Now I'm using the method on a type which implements `Storable`.

```
struct User: Storable {
    ...
}

User.get(by: "userId", completion: { user in
    print(user)
}
```

But the compiler says: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

I want to tell to the compiler "*T is the class who calls the static method*"

I succeed to compile with :

```
static func get<T>(by identifier: String, type: T.Type, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) where T: Decodable

and 

User.get(by: "mprot", type: User.self) { ... }
```

But it seems redundant :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to tell to the compiler *"T is the class who calls the static method"*

Assuming you want to apply your `get` only when *T is the class who calls the static method*, how is this?

```
protocol Storable {
    //...
}

extension Storable where Self: Decodable {
    static func get(by identifier: String, completion: @escaping (Self?) -> Void) {
        //...
    }
}

struct User: Storable, Decodable {
    //...
}
```

This will be compiled successfully:

```
    User.get(by: "userId", completion: { user in
        print(user)
    })
```

Comment: Oh, that's right! I was over-thinking with generic methods, but the solution was simpler! `Self` represents the type which implements the protocol. Thanks for the recall !

Answer (score 0):

T must not be optional. You should have:

```
static func get<T: Decodable>(by identifier: String, completion: @escaping (T) -> ())
```

been called

```
User.get(by: "userId", completion: { (value: User) in ... })
```